# the dual boot is not working. ubuntu installed but startup is with win7 only

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a win 7 laptop. Today I installed ubuntu 12.04 on it.. after installation, it asked for restarting the PC. I clicked on "restart".
after that there should have been a dual boot option or option to choose between win7 and ubuntu.. But there was no dual boot menu.
win 7 start up took place.
what to do now?
how can I access ubuntu?

I had installed ubuntu from a USB drive.
I had temporarily booted from USB.
now how to run ubuntu?

replies are appriciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps laid out in [Boot Repair wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).  It should help you fix your boot issues.